# Name search gem for Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, search, ruby-on-rails-4

I need to be able to search for partial names in my database. Is there a good gem I can install in my Rails project to do this? For example, a name 'Smith' should come up if I search for 'mit'. Not mandatory, but would be nice if phonetic spellings would match too, so 'Mitch' would come up after searching for 'Mich'. Would also be a nice bonus if nicknames matched. So a search of 'Jim' would bring up 'James'.

I'm using Heroku with PostgreSQL. I'd be fine with using PostgreSQL-specific code to accomplish the above.

Answer (score 1):

There is a very good gem used for searching meta_search.

https://github.com/ernie/meta_search

It provides appropriate helpers for searching content. Like if you want to find user record named 'Smith' by typing 'mit'. You can:

In Controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @search = User.search(params[:search])
    ....
  end
  ...
end
```

In view:

```
<%= form_for @search do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :name_contains, 'Name' %>
  <%= f.text_field :name_contains %>
  <%= f.submit 'Search' %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are using postgresql I would recommend using its search capabilities through [textacular](https://github.com/textacular/textacular)

You will find everything you need to install and use it on the Readme page.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use [this railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/343-full-text-search-in-postgresql) as a guide. Is a pro episode, so if you don't have a pro account, anyway you could check the code in [github](https://github.com/railscasts/343-full-text-search-in-postgresql).

Comment: That railscast was great. Though the mechanisms suggested do not work to search for 'mit' and brings up a 'Smith'.